# Using solr facets as filters

Tags: solr

When querying solr for products I also return the facets. For fields such as category, size, colour, price.

So I do something along the lines of:

```
solr.search(*:*, **{'start': 0,
                    'rows': 50,
                    'defType': 'edismax',
                    'fq': '(category=Shoes)',
                    'facet': 'true',
                    'facet.limit': -1,
                    'facet.field': ['size', 'colour', 'price'],
                    'facet.mincount': 0})
```

If I query for category `"Shoes"` I see the possible size, colours and prices which match that category. Now if I add to the filter `(colour:Red)` then all the other possible colours will disappear which is logical as its now filtered on the colour but the user might want to choose two colours.

What is the a better/the usual way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this by adding tags to your `fq`'s and then excluding those tags when creating the facets. An example is show in [Faceting - LocalParameters for Faceting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-LocalParametersforFaceting):

> To return counts for doctype values that are currently not selected, tag filters that directly constrain doctype, and exclude those filters when faceting on doctype.
>
> `q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype`
>
> Filter exclusion is supported for all types of facets. Both the tag and ex local parameters may specify multiple values by separating them with commas.

The implementation would then just OR the different selected values for each filter together in the `fq` for that filter (so you get `color:red OR color:blue` or `color:(red OR blue)`.

Yonik also [has an example on his blog that's very close to your use-case](http://yonik.com/multi-select-faceting/), but it uses the same method as shown in the reference manual above.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. This is exactly what I want and helps a great deal.